# redirect user from page to another with a message

Tags: php

I have 2 PHP pages, 'users list' and 'create a user'. if I create new user successfully the page will redirect me to 'users list' page and show the new created user. the question is how I can make 'user list' page show message like 'new user was created successfully' when redirecting the client to 'user list' page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope Its Solve Your Problem..

```
<?php
$msg="create new user successfully ";
header('users-list.php?msg='.$msg);
?>
```

Comment: Beware! The code from this response, while points to a viable solution, it is not correct, because it does not encode the `$msg` query parameter value.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1: Use a query parameter**
You can redirect to something `users-list.php?create=successful`. Then testing the presence (and eventually value) of the `create` GET param can tell when a message has to be displayed.

**Solution 2: Store it in the session**
Another solution would be to store something in the user's session, that will tell you in the other page that a message has to be displayed. This something could be the message itself or just a flag.